# Auto generated tic-tac-toe

Tags: c#

this is working

```
            int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i != ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n != COLS; n++)
            {
                if (gameArray[i, n] == 1)
                {
                    labels[index].Text = "X";
                }
                else if (gameArray[i, n] == 0)
                {
                    labels[index].Text = "O";
                }
                index += 1;
            }
        }
```

I'm doing an automated tic-tac-toe game in c#. I can only get the labels to display either all X's or all O's its never mixed its one or the other in all 9 labels. Below is how I am getting the x or o values.

```
// initialize our game array
for (int i = 0; i != ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j != COLS; j++)
    {
        gameArray[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 2);
    }
}

// Add the x's and o's to our labels
foreach (int item in gameArray)
{
    foreach (Label myLabel in labels)
    {
        if (item == 1)
            myLabel.Text = "X";
        if (item == 0)
            myLabel.Text = "O";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Have they taught you how to use the debugger yet?

Comment: Don't add `solved` to the title - just mark the answer that helped you with the check box!

Answer (score 3):

you are going through each item,  then for EVERY label, you are setting X or O based on that item.

So its either going to be all X or all O depending on what the last item is.

You need a way to associate labels to items.  If you know that both arrays are 9 long....

```
for(int c=0; c<COLS c++)
{
   for(r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
   {
    if(gameArray[r,c] == 1)
    {
       labels[r*COLS+c].Text = "X";
    }
    else if(gameArray[r,c] == 0)
    { 
       labels[r*COLS+c].Text = "O";
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: Also, you can do both the initializing of the array AND setting the value of the corresponding label in the same loop.

Comment: the gameArray is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: no idea how your labels are done visually, may have to adjust how you iterate the dimensions to match your labels

Comment: His opening statements are correct and the root of the problem, regardless of his example. Besides which, if gameArray is 2 dimensional why not make labels 2D also to make the association more logical?

Answer (score 0):

the generation is too quick that it's only using the same seed for the random number. generate a new seeded instance of rand every time you try to generate a number.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, given that labels is a two dimensional array as well:

```
for (int i = 0; i != ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j != COLS; j++)
    {
      var item = rand.Next(0, 2);
      gameArray[i, j] = item; 
      var myLabel = labels[i,j];

      if (item == 1)
        myLabel.Text = "X";
      if(item == 0)
        myLabel.Text = "O"; 
    }
}
```

If labels ins one dimensional replace:

```
var myLabel = labels[i,j];
```

with:

```
var myLabel = labels[i+j];
```